# Method to calculate the accuracy of template object matching object in an image in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm aware there are various template matching algorithms provided by the [opencv module](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html). However most of these seem to mainly draw rectangles around the matched object in the image. Hence I was wondering if there is a method to calculate the area of the matched object with the template object in order to get an accuracy value?

Comment: None of the OpenCV template matching algorithms draw any rectangles. It's the example script that draws a rectangle to show you where the best match is located. | I'm not sure what you mean by the rest -- the area of the matched object is the same as that of the template. As for the "accuracy value"... `cv2.matchTemplate` already gives you an array of quality metrics, that you then use `cv2.minMaxLoc` on to find the best quality match.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how the template matching works here:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Most notably, the rectangle is drawn in a call to `rectangle(...)` and is not part of the template matching. You will see the score of the matching at each possible location as the result of `matchTemplate()`. If you want to compare multiple scales, you can create multiple images of the template you're trying to match at different sizes, and then find the best matching score across scales.